# how to automate synchronization between propertybase.com listing and mysite sql server db?

Tags: c#, asp.net, synchronization, salesforce

I want synchronize mysite sqlserver DB with the listing in propertybase,com (salesforce child company) automatically, I mean that I don't have to run any web form manually, instead when I click the refresh listing button and my DB also gets updated. It is already implemented in mysite but the problem is that the other developer guy who developed this site did compile most of the code to DLLz. The query for weblisting is given in [here](http://support.propertybase.com/entries/441730-weblisting)

Comment: Do you have a salesforce account and access to their API's (I'm not sure that the API's will help you with scraping related sites)?

Comment: yes I have access to salesforce account and API's but I am not sure how to use them, as I am new to asp.net as well as salesforce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to consider an external sync solution. We have two running in parallel to sync sf accounts with onsite billing systems. One goes through jitterbit, the other through BizTalk. That way your databases will be in sync and your site would be none the wiser.

Comment: as I said I have no idea about salesforce.com or propertybase.com, so I am still in dark and besides my client isn't ready to invest more alongside with propertybase.com fees

Comment: jitterbit is open source so if you know how to use it you can get away with (your) labor costs alone. As for the rest, I doubt you'll find any automated system unless propertybase.com itself provides it. Integration tasks are rarely ready "out-of-the-box". They wil especially be difficult for you to create in code if you are novice in both asp.net and salesforce.

Comment: after all this time, now I can finally make some sense out of your wiser words. cheerios